# textbox validation expression property alphanumerical

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation, textbox

I'm working with a simple `RegularExpressionValidator`. The textbox has to be 14 digits long (exactly 14). So, I use `ValidationExpression="\d{14}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` but that instance just allow numbers, and I need letters also (to be clear, no special characters or dots, semi-colons, only numbers and letters).

What would fit better than `"\d{14}"` ?

thanks!

Comment: @XtianMacedo It works, how this "code" format is call ? thank you!

Comment: I suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for a good resource on regex building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\d replaces only digit characters. 
Try with \w which replaces letters and also numbers.

So your expression should be:

```
<asp ValidationExpression="\w{14}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: \w will match underscores, which I don't think the OP wants.

Comment: XtianMacedo already answer the question, but it's good to read more options, thank you guys!